# How can I print or list all file/directory names in a directory with "\" before space in their names using "ls" command?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

I am trying to make softlinks for all the files and directories under some directory, but some of them has space. Since we have to use full name like "one\ two\ three\ file". How can we list the names using ls command. I can do it writing some script or code but, can't we do the same using ls command?

If a directory is named "foo bar" 
I want the result as foo\ bar.

Comment: Would `find -print0 | xargs -0` work?

Comment: Thanks, but it shows "./foo bar" for one of the directory whereas I want "foo\ bar".

Comment: From your description, printing with `\`s seems a secondary task, if what you actually want is to make softlinks. `find srcdir -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 ln -s` should do the job.

Comment: Yes, that may work. But my main question remains the same. I am more curious on how can I get "\" before spaces in file/directory names using ls. Please see if you help on that. Thanks.

Comment: `xargs` is the correct solution to your problem. `find -exec` might work if certain assumptions are met. You might get away with feeding `ls -1` into `while read` loop by properly quoting shell variables. Yet you insist that answer must work under some bogus requirements without even explaining how these requirements came to be. Please update your question with clear statement why neither `xargs` not `find` will work in your particular situation.